# How to inject autogenerated classes?

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I'm using `CXF` to autogenerate some webservice client classes. The result looks similar to:

```
@WebServiceClient
public class TheService extends Service {
}
```

So far I used these services with `new TheService()`, but as I'm using `Spring` now I'd like to also inject my autogenerated classes. It is obviously not a good idea to edit the generated classes as they might be regenerated in the future (eg on webservice updates). So I cannot annotate them eg with `@Service`.

But how can I then use `@Autowired private TheService service`? Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime when client class is generated, if there is a possiblity of class name to get changed (I faced this class name change when upgrading from Axis 1.1 to Axis 2 for webservice client stub generation) then you can try it with Spring XML configuration instead of annotations.

```
    <bean id="clientStub" class="com.package1.TheService">
    ....
    </bean>
```

Refer this id(clientstub) in the class you want to access it.

```
    <bean id="accessingClass" class="com.package2.AccessingClass">
       <property name="service" ref="clientStub" />
    </bean>
    Public class AccessingClass{
      private Service service;
      ....
    }
```

Only place you need to make the change is in class(with generated class name) of bean definition with id="clientStub"
So any changes to TheService className will be absorbed and you dont have to make changes in the class accessing this clientstub as Spring takes care of the change by id.

Comment: That's a great idea using xml config instead of annotations.